# How might I pass a list as a variable in a python gql query?

Tags: python, graphql, gql, graphql-python

Based on the example from [the gql documentation](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/basic_usage.html), I have the below, working query:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport

# Select your transport with a defined url endpoint
transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url="https://data.rcsb.org/graphql")

# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

# Provide a GraphQL query
query = gql(
    """
    {
        entries(entry_ids: ["4HHB", "5cbg", "3j3Q"]) {
            assemblies {
                pdbx_struct_assembly {
                    id
                    details
                }
            }
        }
    }


"""
)



# Execute the query on the transport
result = client.execute(query)
print(result)
```

which prints, correctly:

```
{'entries': [{'assemblies': [{'pdbx_struct_assembly': {'id': '1', 'details': 'author_and_software_defined_assembly'}}]}, {'assemblies': [{'pdbx_struct_assembly': {'id': '1', 'details': 'author_and_software_defined_assembly'}}, {'pdbx_struct_assembly': {'id': '2', 'details': 'author_and_software_defined_assembly'}}, {'pdbx_struct_assembly': {'id': '3', 'details': 'author_and_software_defined_assembly'}}]}, {'assemblies': [{'pdbx_struct_assembly': {'id': '1', 'details': 'author_defined_assembly'}}]}]}
```

But I want to be able to programmatically give input to the endpoint as a list as a variable in place of `["4HHB", "5cbg", "3j3Q"]`. How can I do this?

Based again on the documentation, I came up with the below, but it does not work because GQL does not recognize `List!` as valid:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport

# Select your transport with a defined url endpoint
transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url="https://data.rcsb.org/graphql")

# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

# Provide a GraphQL query
query = gql(
    """
    query getAssembliesInfo ($ids_list: List) {
    
        entries(entry_ids: $ids_list) {
            assemblies {
                pdbx_struct_assembly {
                    id
                    details
                }
            }
        }
        
    }


"""
)


pdbs =  ["4HHB", "5cbg", "3j3Q"]
params = {'ids_list': pdbs}

# Execute the query on the transport
result = client.execute(query, variable_values=params)
print(result)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nfs/turbo/umms-petefred/jaschwa/HDPRED/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gql/client.py", line 388, in execute
    data = loop.run_until_complete(
  File "/nfs/turbo/umms-petefred/jaschwa/HDPRED/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/nfs/turbo/umms-petefred/jaschwa/HDPRED/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gql/client.py", line 285, in execute_async
    return await session.execute(
  File "/nfs/turbo/umms-petefred/jaschwa/HDPRED/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gql/client.py", line 1220, in execute
    result = await self._execute(
  File "/nfs/turbo/umms-petefred/jaschwa/HDPRED/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gql/client.py", line 1111, in _execute
    self.client.validate(document)
  File "/nfs/turbo/umms-petefred/jaschwa/HDPRED/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gql/client.py", line 149, in validate
    raise validation_errors[0]
graphql.error.graphql_error.GraphQLError: Unknown type 'List'. Did you mean 'Int'?

GraphQL request:2:41
1 |
2 |     query getAssembliesInfo ($ids_list: List) {
  |                                         ^
3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I needed to get out of python land and define a typed list with `[String!]!`:

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport

# Select your transport with a defined url endpoint
transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url="https://data.rcsb.org/graphql")

# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)

# Provide a GraphQL query
query = gql(
    """
    query getAssembliesInfo ($ids_list: [String!]!) {
    
        entries(entry_ids: $ids_list) {
            assemblies {
                pdbx_struct_assembly {
                    id
                    details
                }
            }
        }
        
    }


"""
)


pdbs =  ["4HHB", "5cbg", "3j3Q"]
params = {'ids_list': pdbs}

# Execute the query on the transport
result = client.execute(query, variable_values=params)
print(result)
```